# grpc java code generated ignoring Bool field

Tags: grpc-java

I am using protoc-jar-maven-plugin (3.11.4) in eclipse to auto generate the grpc stubs from proto file.
When generating code, i noticed the my Bool data type fields from proto ("proto3") are not coming as part of classes generated.

Not sure why only bool datatype fields are getting missed, where as all string datatype are coming properly.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this issue. Here's `pom.xml` and the proto: https://gist.github.com/sergiitk/d16891f15b4e2506848f40ebfb62a7ec

I used `helloworld.proto` example from grpc-java repo, and added `bool result = 2;` to `HelloReply`.
After running maven, resulting `HelloReply.java` has the result field, as expected:

```java
public static final int RESULT_FIELD_NUMBER = 2;
private boolean result_;
/**
 * <code>bool result = 2;</code>
 * @return The result.
 */
public boolean getResult() {
  return result_;
}
```

Here's maven log:

```
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.11.4:run (default) @ playground-maven ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.11.4
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.11.4, detected platform: osx-x86_64 (mac os x/x86_64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.11.4/protoc-3.11.4-osx-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [/var/folders/rv/f07pfszx34d0lrp44_lw7zhw00rg80/T/protocjar8753023980661031420/bin/protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.11.4
[INFO] Protoc command: /var/folders/rv/f07pfszx34d0lrp44_lw7zhw00rg80/T/protocjar8753023980661031420/bin/protoc.exe
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     /Users/sergiitk/Development/playground/playground-maven/src/main/protobuf
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: /Users/sergiitk/Development/playground/playground-maven/target/generated-sources (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] /Users/sergiitk/Development/playground/playground-maven/target/generated-sources does not exist. Creating...
[INFO]     Processing (java): helloworld.proto
protoc-jar: executing: [/var/folders/rv/f07pfszx34d0lrp44_lw7zhw00rg80/T/protocjar8753023980661031420/bin/protoc.exe, -I/Users/sergiitk/Development/playground/playground-maven/src/main/protobuf, --java_out=/Users/sergiitk/Development/playground/playground-maven/target/generated-sources, /Users/sergiitk/Development/playground/playground-maven/src/main/protobuf/helloworld.proto]
[INFO] Adding generated sources (java): /Users/sergiitk/Development/playground/playground-maven/target/generated-sources
```